# IE11だとjavascriptのアコーディオンが動かない

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$(function() {
  // 初期開閉状態設定
  $(".accordionbox dt")
    .filter((i, e) => isActive($(e).next()))
    .each((i, e) => toggle($(e)));

  $(".accordionbox dt").on("click", function() {
    toggle($(this));
  });
});

function toggle($dt) {
  $dt.next().slideToggle(100);
  // activeが存在する場合
  if ($dt.children(".accordion_icon").hasClass('active')) {
    // activeを削除
    $dt.children(".accordion_icon").removeClass('active');
  } else {
    // activeを追加
    $dt.children(".accordion_icon").addClass('active');
  }
}

// 初期開閉状態の判定
function isActive($dd) {
  // 特定のラジオボタンをチェックしているか
  if ($dd.find('input[type="radio"].close:checked').length)
    return false;
  // チェックボックスをチェックしているか
  if ($dd.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length)
    return true;
  // テキストボックスに入力があるか
  if ($dd.find('input[type="text"]').filter((i, e) => $(e).val()).length)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.accordionbox {
  width: 50%;
  background: #FBDBC4;
  margin: 10px auto 40px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.accordionlist dt {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
}

.accordionlist dt:first-child {
  border-top: none !important;
}

.accordionlist dt .title {
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.accordionlist dd {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 0 20px 15px;
}

.accordion_icon,
.accordion_icon span {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .4s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion_icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.accordion_icon span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #F88789;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
}

.accordion_icon span:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 5px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.accordion_icon span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 5px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/*＋、－切り替え*/

.accordion_icon.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

.accordion_icon.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 5px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion" class="accordionbox">
  <dl class="accordionlist">
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>チェック済</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>未チェック</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="checkbox" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>入力済</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="text" value="hoge" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>未入力</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="text" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>特定のラジオボタンチェック済</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="radio" class="close" checked="checked" /><input type="text" value="hoge" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>特定のラジオボタン未チェック</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="radio" class="close" /><input type="text" value="hoge" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>option valueデータあり</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd>
    <p>星座:
<select name="horoscope">
<option value="Aries">おひつじ座</option>
<option value="Taurus">おうし座</option>
<option value="Gemini">ふたご座</option>
<option value="Cancer">かに座</option>
<option value="Leo" selected>しし座</option>
<option value="Virgo">おとめ座</option>
<option value="Libra">てんびん座</option>
<option value="Scorpio" disabled>さそり座</option>
<option value="Saggitarius">いて座</option>
<option value="Capricorn">やぎ座</option>
<option value="Aquarius">みずがめ座</option>
<option value="Pisces">うお座</option>
</select></p>
    </dd> 
  </dl>
</div>
```

IE11だとjavascriptのアコーディオンが動きません。
入力済みのデータがあるときにアコーディオンを開いた状態にしたいです。
チェックボックスにチェックしていない状態なのにアコーディオンが入力がないのに開くことがあります。
またiframeの中に文章を書いたときは
if ($dd.find('input[type="text"]').filter((i, e) => $(e).val()).length)
    return true;
ではうまくいきません。
別の方法があるのでしょうか。
option valueで選択して登録された場合もデータがあるように開いた状態にするにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: allow 関数でエラーになっていませんか？（コンソールにエラーが出ていないでしょうか）

Comment: コンソールにallow関数のエラーは出ていないです。

Comment: 私の環境(IE11,Windows10)では"=>"を使っているところをとりあえず削除したらアコーディオン開閉はとりあえず動きました、としか言いようがないです・・・。

Comment: 本家のQAのようにIE11ではarrowはNGだと思います。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/arrow-function-not-working-in-ie-why

Comment: arrow関数を使わないコードに変えたらうまくいきました。

Answer (score 1):

質問文のコードが IE11 で動作しない原因は、[コメント欄に書かれている](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/52628/ie11%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8javascript%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%81%8C%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84#comment55043_52628)ように、**アロー関数が IE11 では使用出来ないため**です。質問文のコードを Babel を用いて変換をすると、以下のようになります。

```
$(function () {
  // 初期開閉状態設定
  $(".accordionbox dt").filter(function (i, e) {
    return isActive($(e).next());
  }).each(function (i, e) {
    return toggle($(e));
  });
  $(".accordionbox dt").on("click", function () {
    toggle($(this));
  });
});

function toggle($dt) {
  $dt.next().slideToggle(100); // activeが存在する場合

  if ($dt.children(".accordion_icon").hasClass('active')) {
    // activeを削除
    $dt.children(".accordion_icon").removeClass('active');
  } else {
    // activeを追加
    $dt.children(".accordion_icon").addClass('active');
  }
} // 初期開閉状態の判定


function isActive($dd) {
  // 特定のラジオボタンをチェックしているか
  if ($dd.find('input[type="radio"].close:checked').length) return false; // チェックボックスをチェックしているか

  if ($dd.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) return true; // テキストボックスに入力があるか

  if ($dd.find('input[type="text"]').filter(function (i, e) {
    return $(e).val();
  }).length) return true;
  return false;
}
```

---

次に、 `select` 要素でいずれかの項目を選択しているときに、アコーディオンメニューを開いた状態にするためには、 jQuery の拡張機能である `selected` セレクターを用いることが出来ます。`selected` セレクターを使うことで、 **`option` 要素のうち選択されているすべての要素を得る**ことが出来ます。

```
$(function() {
  // 初期開閉状態設定
  $(".accordionbox dt").filter(function(i, e) {
    return isActive($(e).next());
  }).each(function(i, e) {
    return toggle($(e));
  });
  $(".accordionbox dt").on("click", function() {
    toggle($(this));
  });
});

function toggle($dt) {
  $dt.next().slideToggle(100); // activeが存在する場合

  if ($dt.children(".accordion_icon").hasClass('active')) {
    // activeを削除
    $dt.children(".accordion_icon").removeClass('active');
  } else {
    // activeを追加
    $dt.children(".accordion_icon").addClass('active');
  }
} // 初期開閉状態の判定


function isActive($dd) {
  // 特定のラジオボタンをチェックしているか
  if ($dd.find('input[type="radio"].close:checked').length) return true; // ラジオボタンをチェックしているか ( false から true に修正 )

  if ($dd.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) return true; // テキストボックスに入力があるか

  if ($dd.find('select option:selected').length) return true; // 追記箇所: 選択されている項目があるか

  if ($dd.find('input[type="text"]').filter(function(i, e) {
      if ($(e).prev('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)').length) return; // 追記箇所: テキストボックスが置かれていても、ラジオボタンがあればそれによって判定する
      return $(e).val();
    }).length) return true;
  return false;
}
```

---

長くなってしまうため折りたたんでいますが、最終的には以下のコードスニペットのようにすることで、質問者さんの実現したいことが行えると思います。

```js
$(function() {
  // 初期開閉状態設定
  $(".accordionbox dt").filter(function(i, e) {
    return isActive($(e).next());
  }).each(function(i, e) {
    return toggle($(e));
  });
  $(".accordionbox dt").on("click", function() {
    toggle($(this));
  });
});

function toggle($dt) {
  $dt.next().slideToggle(100); // activeが存在する場合

  if ($dt.children(".accordion_icon").hasClass('active')) {
    // activeを削除
    $dt.children(".accordion_icon").removeClass('active');
  } else {
    // activeを追加
    $dt.children(".accordion_icon").addClass('active');
  }
} // 初期開閉状態の判定


function isActive($dd) {
  // 特定のラジオボタンをチェックしているか
  if ($dd.find('input[type="radio"].close:checked').length) return true; // ラジオボタンをチェックしているか ( false から true に修正 )

  if ($dd.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) return true; // テキストボックスに入力があるか

  if ($dd.find('select option:selected').length) return true; // 追記箇所: 選択されている項目があるか

  if ($dd.find('input[type="text"]').filter(function(i, e) {
      if ($(e).prev('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)').length) return; // 追記箇所: テキストボックスが置かれていても、ラジオボタンがあればそれによって判定する
      return $(e).val();
    }).length) return true;
  return false;
}
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.accordionbox {
  width: 50%;
  background: #FBDBC4;
  margin: 10px auto 40px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.accordionlist dt {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
}

.accordionlist dt:first-child {
  border-top: none !important;
}

.accordionlist dt .title {
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.accordionlist dd {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 0 20px 15px;
}

.accordion_icon,
.accordion_icon span {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .4s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion_icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.accordion_icon span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #F88789;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
}

.accordion_icon span:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 5px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.accordion_icon span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 5px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/*＋、－切り替え*/

.accordion_icon.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

.accordion_icon.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 5px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion" class="accordionbox">
  <dl class="accordionlist">
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>チェック済</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>未チェック</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="checkbox" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>入力済</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="text" value="hoge" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>未入力</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="text" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>特定のラジオボタンチェック済</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="radio" class="close" checked="checked" /><input type="text" value="hoge" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>特定のラジオボタン未チェック</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="radio" class="close" /><input type="text" value="hoge" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>option valueデータあり</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      <p>星座:
        <select name="horoscope">
          <option value="Aries">おひつじ座</option>
          <option value="Taurus">おうし座</option>
          <option value="Gemini">ふたご座</option>
          <option value="Cancer">かに座</option>
          <option value="Leo" selected>しし座</option>
          <option value="Virgo">おとめ座</option>
          <option value="Libra">てんびん座</option>
          <option value="Scorpio" disabled>さそり座</option>
          <option value="Saggitarius">いて座</option>
          <option value="Capricorn">やぎ座</option>
          <option value="Aquarius">みずがめ座</option>
          <option value="Pisces">うお座</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```